# How to set value to state for recursive rendered component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, event-handling, setstate

I need to make a component. This should be a editable tree component. I tried a lot, but i can't handle issue. I don't use any libraries such as redux. I made a component it travel all json object recusively. Now, At onChange event, it passes param (path of key) according to this path I wrote a function called 'updateObjectValueByPath' updates that value. Now I need to save this json object to a state. But I can't save latest version, when I switch input field 'datas' object reset its value. Here is my code, maybe I can't explain myself clearly. Hope code can help. Thanks for all..

```
  render() {
    let json = this.state.json;
    const data = this.props.data;
    const path = this.props.path; 

    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      return data.map((element, index) => {
        let currentPath = `${path}.${index}`;
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <CCol sm={12}>
              <CInputGroup>
                <CCol sm={3}>
                  <CInputGroupPrepend>
                    <CListGroup accent>
                      <CListGroupItem key="id" accent="success">
                        {this.props.properties}
                        {index + 1} :
                      </CListGroupItem>
                    </CListGroup>
                  </CInputGroupPrepend>
                </CCol>
                <CCol sm={5}>
                  {index === 0 ? (
                    <CButton color="warning" onClick={() => this.addItem(path)}>
                      Add
                    </CButton>
                  ) : null}
                </CCol>
                <CCol sm={4}>
                  <CButton
                    color="danger"
                    onClick={() => this.removeItem(path, index)}
                  >
                    Remove
                  </CButton>
                </CCol>
              </CInputGroup>
            </CCol>
            <CCol>
              <JsonTree
                path={currentPath}
                data={element}
                arrayIndex={index}
                key={currentPath}
                jsonContent={this.state.json}
              ></JsonTree>
            </CCol>
          </div>
        );
      });
    } else if (data instanceof Object) {
      //      console.log(this.props.jsonContent);
      return Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
        let currentPath = path !== "" ? `${path}.${key}` : key;
        return (
          <JsonTree
            data={data[key]}
            path={currentPath}
            key={currentPath}
            properties={key}
            jsonContent={this.state.json}
          />
        );
      });
    } else {
      //    console.log(this.props.jsonContent);
      return (
        <div>
          {console.log(this.state.json)}
          {/*         {this.setState({ json: this.state.den })} */}
          <CCol sm={12} key={path}>
            <CInputGroup>
              <CCol sm={3}>
                <CInputGroupPrepend>
                  <CListGroup accent>
                    <CListGroupItem key="id" accent="primary">
                      {this.props.properties}:
                    </CListGroupItem>
                  </CListGroup>
                </CInputGroupPrepend>
              </CCol>
              <CCol sm={9}>
                {/*           number kabul edecek value olarak */}
                {typeof data === "number" ? (
                  <CInput
                    id={path}
                    name={path}
                    defaultValue={data}
                    type="number"
                    style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
                    //          disabled={!this.props.isEditable}
                    onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event, path, json)}
                  />
                ) : typeof data === "string" ? (
                  <CInput
                    id={path}
                    name={path}
                    type="text"
                    defaultValue={data}
                    style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
                    //           disabled={!this.props.isEditable}
                    onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event, path, json)}
                  />
                ) : null}
              </CCol>
            </CInputGroup>
          </CCol>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

```
  handleChange = (event, path, datas) => {
    const seperatedPath = path.split(".");

    let arrayPath = seperatedPath.map((v) => (isFinite(v) ? +v : v));

    let value = event.target.value;

    let newData = this.updateObjectValueByPath(arrayPath, datas, value);
    console.log(newData); 

    this.setState({ json: newData });
  };
```

```
  updateObjectValueByPath = (arrayPath, datas, value) => {
    const key = arrayPath[0];
    if (Array.isArray(datas) && datas !== null) {
      if (arrayPath.length > 1) {
        return datas.map((el, index) => {
          if (index === key) {
            return this.updateObjectValueByPath(
              arrayPath.slice(1, arrayPath.length),
              el,
              value
            );
          }

          return el;
        }, []);
      }

      return [...datas, value];
    }

    if (typeof datas === "object" && !Array.isArray(datas) && datas !== null) {
      if (arrayPath.length > 1) {
        return {
          ...datas,
          [key]: this.updateObjectValueByPath(
            arrayPath.slice(1, arrayPath.length),
            datas[key],
            value
          ),
        };
      }
      return { ...datas, [key]: value };
    }
    return datas;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved that issue, for solution:

I wrote a callback function which call that class. And this callback prop also should be written in recursive field like that;

```
          <JsonTree
            data={data[key]}
            path={currentPath}
            key={currentPath}
            properties={key}
            jsonContent={this.state.json}
            callback={this.props.callback}
          />
```

Then, when onchange event triggered, call this callback and sent newData as param.

```
    let newData = this.updateObjectValueByPath({ arrayPath, datas, value });
    console.log(newData);
    this.props.callback(newData);
```

By doing this, we are traversing the new object as a parameter through the parent.